# How to use Promise's reject?

Tags: ionic2, rxjs, ionic3

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) says

**resolve is**

> The Promise.resolve(value) method returns a Promise object that is
>   resolved with the given value.

**reject is**

> The Promise.reject(reason) method returns a Promise object that is
>   rejected with the given reason.

I understand the uses of **resolve** but what will be the uses of **reject** and **when to use it** ?

Comment: I think this question would fall under the category of "too broad" but one example of a situation where you could use `Promise.reject` would be if you had a function that was defined to return a promise, but you wanted to synchronously validate some of its arguments: `function myFunc(a, b) { if (!a) { return Promise.reject(new Error('a is required')); } return theAsynchronousThing(a, b); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise.reject is promise's way of throwing errors. Usually you would have a condition inside of your promise:

```
const user = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 17
}

const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (user.age > 18) {
        resolve('Welcome!');
    } else {
        reject(new Error('Too young!'));
    }        
});
```

You can then chain `then` and `catch` methods to handle the results of resolve and reject respectively.

```
p.then(message => {
    console.log(message); // 'Welcome!', if promise resolves, won't work with age of 17
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err); // 'Too young!', because promise was rejected
});
```

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few examples this statement can be used for:

Function defined to return a Promise, however you perform some sync checks and would like to return an error:

```
function request(data) {
   if (!data) return Promise.reject("Empty data!");
   // other logic
}
```

Unit tests, for example you would like to test that default data is used if service returns error (rejected promise):

```
const mockService = mock(Service);
// mock request method to return rejected promise
when(mockService.performRequest()).thenReturn(Promise.reject("Failed!"));

// inject mock instance and check that default data used if service failed
const sut = new ClassUnderTest(mockService);
expect(sut.getData()).to.eq("Default data");
```